How to hide a folder in VS Code except for certain files?
I'm trying to configure Visual Studio Code to hide a specific folder from both the left panel and the search results, but I want to keep certain file(s) within that folder visible.
Here's what I have in my .vscode/settings.json:
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "foo/**": true,
        "foo/bar.baz": false
    },
}

This configuration hides the entire foo folder, including the bar.baz file, which I want to keep visible.
How can I achieve this?
I want to:

Hide the foo folder from the left panel.
Exclude the foo folder from search results.
Keep specific files (like bar.baz) within the foo folder visible and searchable.

